# Could someone please assist with using Maven Clean to make a Java SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Java. Am currently trying to modify some library code and then use a SNAPSHOT jar of that to use in my current project. In IntelliJ IDEA CE, I used the Maven Projects Tool Window and hit the Lifecyle -> Clean command to attempt to make the Snapshot.

I saw the following output...

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <NAME> 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ <NAME> ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.219 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-22T11:36:03-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Two questions:
1) Where is that SNAPSHOT jar located?
2) How do I make a SNAPSHOT jar that includes all dependencies?

EDIT: Resolved. Please see comments.

Comment: mvn clean cleans the output directory... use mvn install

Comment: mvn install creates the package and adds it to your local .m2 repository; mvn deploy does that and publishes it to a remote repository (e.g. Nexus).

Comment: can you please post it as an answer or future reference.